# What is the equivalent of .closest jQuery function in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, popup

I am tryin to implement a custom popup window in Angular. The problem is when clicking outside of the popup when opened i dont know how to implement it easily without an overlay. I have found that in libraries based on jQuery is common to use the `.closest` function for this but i can not find an alternative in plain Javascript way.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663941/finding-closest-element-without-jquery

Comment: `event.target` can be used?

Comment: but it uses it by tagname

Comment: is ```event.target``` cross browser?

Comment: Any workaround on this Blacksonic?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need `closest` method for your task. To be able to close popup on clicking anywhere outside of it, you should bind a click event handler on `body` (or `document`) element and just close popup if this event is detected there.

It will work due to the fact, that click event bubbles up the DOM tree, eventually reaching topmost element like `body` for example.

Then you make sure you prevent event propagation when event is initialized **within** popup itself, because you don't click event to reach the body (where if handled there popup will be closed). For this you bind one more click event on `popup` container and when it occurs you prevent its further propagation:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

So when you interact with popup and its contents clicking inside, doing something, click events never reach the body, so pop up never close. But once you click outside of the popup - bubbling click event will be handled by `body` handler and will close popup.

Comment: The problem with this is that any other element can stop event propagation and it would break it.