# Change text to show currently selected item in the select

Tags: javascript

I would like to change the appropriate line when a change has been done on a select.

I have something like that :

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select id="ListeElement" name ="ListeElement" onchange="changeLabel(this)"> 
           <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option> 
           <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
        </select> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <span id="labelElement" name="labelElement" onchange="changeLabel(this)">option</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select id="ListeElement" name="ListeElement" onchange="changeLabel();"> 
           <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option> 
           <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
        </select> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <span id="labelElement" name="labelElement" onchange="changeLabel()">option</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/fx7bkvwh/3/)

So if I change the first select I would like to change my first label with the value selected.

I know that an ID is unique but I can't change my html code.

I can only add JavaScript method.

Thx

Comment: all options have value="Option 1"?

Comment: What do you want to happen when the select changes? Do you want the text in the first row td and the second row td to change? Or just one of those?

Comment: You can't have proper markup? Having duplicate IDs is preposterous. If you can use JS then I suggest you change the IDs with `var id = document.querySelector('select'); id.setAttribute('id', 'UNIQUEID');`

Comment: Having same ID for multiple tags is a wrong way of coding. In a larger application, you might end up realizing that you have messed up. And correcting that would be frustrating. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Not all option has value option 1 that was my mistake sry,

I know that is really wrong to duplicate ID but I can't change it even with javascript. because It can break all the logic behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're essentially asking for a way to find the closest element that matches a selector. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26997490/2382729) answer, which provides a function for exactly that.

Working solution (note that I changed the value attributes of the option objects to different values so that you can see the change):

```js
function changeLabel(that){
    closest(that, "#labelElement").innerHTML = that.options[that.selectedIndex].value;
}

function closest(el, sel) {
    if (el != null)
        return el.matches(sel) ? el 
            : (el.querySelector(sel) 
                || closest(el.parentNode, sel));
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="ListeElement" name ="ListeElement" onchange="changeLabel(this)"> 
               <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option> 
               <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
            </select> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="labelElement">option</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="ListeElement"> 
               <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option> 
               <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
            </select> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <span id="labelElement">option</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thx for your reply but it doesn't work with IE.

object doesn't support this property or method match

Comment: Take a look at the question I linked, it mentions that matches is not supported by IE, and provides a polyfill you can use.