# How to prevent search box from collapsing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autocomplete

I have a search button which displays autocomplete suggestions as the user types as demonstrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/z8qpw3yL/
The issue is that on clicking the `suggested text`, the search bar collapses. I want it such that it should only collapse if the user clicks outside on an empty space.

Comment: it is because you have given width to your search bar on hover only so ass soon as you remove the hover it shrinks back

Comment: So how can I change it 'onclick'

Comment: using js pass the width to that div on click so that it stays with that hide does not shrink

Comment: use focus event...

Comment: @MisterJojo Where should I apply the focus event?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event  or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

Comment: @Avinashjain, when I pass width to that div, it doesn't collapse (just as I wanted) However, the text is disappearing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the jquery click events instead of css hover.

**run the snippet to see how i did it.**

this is the onlick event

```
 $(".searchBox").click(function(){
 $(".searchInput").css({"width":"240px",
    "padding": "0 6px"});
 });
```

this is the click outside event:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) 
{
    var container = $(".searchBox");

    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
         $(".searchInput").css({"width":"0px",
    "padding": "0px"});
    }
});
```

```js
$(".searchBox").click(function(){
 $(".searchInput").css({"width":"240px",
    "padding": "0 6px"});
 });
 
 
 $(document).mouseup(function(e) 
{
    var container = $(".searchBox");

    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
         $(".searchInput").css({"width":"0px",
    "padding": "0px"});
    }
});


 
 function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/

        var dontClose = document.getElementById('searchBox');


  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
              e.preventDefault();

          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

/*An array containing all the country names in the world:*/
var countries = ["Limuru", "Upper Hill", "Machakos", "Mazeras Hill", "Webuye Hill", "Nyambene Hill", "Nyeri Hill", "Menengai Hill", "Kapsoya", "Kiboswa", "Kakamega Hill", "Londiani Hill", "Kericho Hill", "Nyanchua Hill", "Nyadundo Hill", "Narok", "Kapenguria Hill", "Vuria Hill", "Mambrui", "Garissa"];

/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
```

```css
.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-top-left-radius:20px;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;

  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
}

/*when hovering an item:*/
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9; 
}

/*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
.autocomplete-active {
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important; 
  color: #ffffff; 
}



.searchBox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:  translate(-50%,50%);
    background: #2f3640;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding: 10px;

}


.searchBox:hover > .searchButton {
  background: white;
  color : #2f3640;
}

.searchButton {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #2f3640;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.searchInput {
    border:none;
    background: none;
    outline:none;
    float:left;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 0px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<form id="siteSearch" autocomplete="off">
<div id="searchBox" class="searchBox">

    <input id="myInput" class="searchInput"type="text" name="" placeholder="Search Site">
    <button id="submitted" type="button" class="searchButton">
        <i class="material-icons">
            search
        </i>
    </button>
</div>
</form>
<!-- partial -->
```

> [image: Upvote if you like it]

Comment: However, on the mobile phone, touching outside doesn't close the searchBox. Is there a function that caters for mobile touches?

Comment: check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358950/close-menu-when-click-touch-outside-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You should use `focus` in your CSS.
just add this line to your css code:

```
.searchBox > .searchInput:focus {
    width: 240px;
    padding: 0 6px;
}
```