# dynamically delete html input field using JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

I have a form which contains **1 select input field.**

When I select one of the option in the select field. I by default create a **section containing text input field, a close button and a Add Field button to add more input text fields.**

everything is working just fine but I am not sure how to delete dynamically created input field. I am not sure what to use **id or class or name attribute or what** to then find and delete the input field when I click on a delete button next to it.

## my code

HTML CODE

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="extraFieldsLabelHolder"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="extraFields">
      <!-- here I can add as many custom fields I want -->
    </div>
</div>
```

JS CODE

```
 function addFields(){
        var selectVal = document.getElementById('type_id').value;
        if(selectVal === 'checkbox' || selectVal === 'radio'){

            if(!document.getElementById("addBtn")){
                //add input fields
                var extraFieldDIV = document.getElementById("extraFieldsLabelHolder");
                var fieldLabel = document.createElement("label");
                    fieldLabel.setAttribute("for", "extraFields");
                    fieldLabel.setAttribute('id', "extraFieldsLabel")
                    fieldLabel.textContent = "Add Custom Field Options:";
                extraFieldDIV.appendChild(fieldLabel);

  //IT MAY LOOK COMPLEX BUT ITS FAIRLY STRAIGHTFORWARD
  //Code below creates mainDiv and a Div which holds input and a delete btn
                var fieldArea = document.getElementById('extraFields');
                var mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    mainDiv.setAttribute("class", "input_field col-md-4");
                    mainDiv.setAttribute("style", "margin-bottom:10px;");
                fieldArea.appendChild(mainDiv);

                var div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.setAttribute("class", "input-group");
                mainDiv.appendChild(div);

                var input = document.createElement("input");
                    input.setAttribute("type", "text");
                    input.setAttribute("class", "form-control input_field");
                    input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter value...");
                    input.setAttribute("name", "extras[]");
                div.appendChild(input);

                var span = document.createElement("span");
                    span.setAttribute("class", "input-group-btn");
                div.appendChild(span);

                var closeBtn = document.createElement("button");
                    closeBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
                    closeBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-danger");
       //YOU CAN SEE HERE I PASS ONCLICK METHOD but not sure what to do NEXT
       //ALL I GET IS INFO OF A DELETE BUTTON and Not the actual DIV which contains input field too.             
                closeBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "removeInputField(this)");
                span.appendChild(closeBtn);

                var iElement = document.createElement("i");
                    iElement.setAttribute("class", "pe-7s-close");
                    iElement.setAttribute("style", "font-size:20px");
                closeBtn.appendChild(iElement);

                var btnArea = document.getElementById('addFieldBtnHolder');
                var btn = document.createElement("button");
                    btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
                    btn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary");
                    btn.setAttribute("style", "margin-top:15px;");
                    btn.setAttribute("onclick", "addInputField()");
                    btn.textContent = "Add Field";
                    btn.setAttribute('id', "addBtn");
                btnArea.appendChild(btn);
            }

        }else{
            if(document.getElementById("addBtn")) {
                document.getElementById("extraFieldsLabel").remove();
                document.getElementById("addBtn").remove();
                var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('input_field');
                for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
                    inputs[i].remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function addInputField(){

        console.log("test2");
        var fieldArea = document.getElementById('extraFields');
        var mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
        mainDiv.setAttribute("class", "input_field col-md-4");
        mainDiv.setAttribute("style", "margin-bottom:10px;");
        fieldArea.appendChild(mainDiv);

        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("class", "input-group");
        mainDiv.appendChild(div);

        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("type", "text");
        input.setAttribute("class", "form-control input_field");
        input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter value...");
        input.setAttribute("name", "extras[]");
        div.appendChild(input);

        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.setAttribute("class", "input-group-btn");
        div.appendChild(span);

        var closeBtn = document.createElement("button");
        closeBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
        closeBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-danger");
        closeBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "removeInputField(this)");
        span.appendChild(closeBtn);

        var iElement = document.createElement("i");
        iElement.setAttribute("class", "pe-7s-close");
        iElement.setAttribute("style", "font-size:20px");
        closeBtn.appendChild(iElement);
    }

//WHAT LOGIC DO I PUT HERE TO DELETE THE DIV CONTAINING input and delete button?
    function removeInputField (selectedField) {
        console.log("this: ", selectedField.value);

    }
```

Comment: what do you prefer, native js or jquery?

Comment: There's not one event for a user to invoke any function. How do you test this? Are you aware that ids must be unique? If you manage to create more than one element with identical ids that is invalid plus brings about unexpected behavior.

Comment: @plonknimbuzz i prefer native js because i wrote all of it in js. I dont want to have jquery in between if possible

Comment: @zer00ne I was thinking of creating a counter and incrementing id's but then I don't know what is the best way so I asked for some logic I could add. I am open for suggestions

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia Events my friend, I can't guarantee the exact results of your expected layout but I'll do enough so you get a good idea.

Comment: can you include the html code of `type_id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `closest()`.

but its only works on modern browser. to hack that you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35294561/3396168)

```
function removeInputField (selectedField) {
        selectedField.closest('.input_field').remove();
    }
```

see the example

```html
<style>
.input_field{border: 2px solid red;}
</style>

    <script>
 function removeInputField (selectedField) {
        selectedField.closest('.input_field').remove();
    }
 </script>
<div>
 <div class="input_field">i<button onclick="removeInputField(this);">1</button></div>
 <div class="input_field">am<button onclick="removeInputField(this);">2</button></div>
 <div class="input_field">another<button onclick="removeInputField(this);">3</button></div>
 <div class="input_field">element<button onclick="removeInputField(this);">4</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap (which you probably are because OP classes are BS), then you are probably using jQuery (BS API requires jQuery). So this Demo is in jQuery. Here's what it does:

- Starts with 3 buttons <kbd>+</kbd><kbd>⚙</kbd>

  - **ADD** an `fieldset.form-group`
  - **CFG** settings (not functional in Demo)
  - **SUB**mit form data to a [**live test server**](https://httpbin.org)
- Each `fieldset.form-group` has:

  - 3 `<input>`
  - 1 `<textarea>`
  - 2 `<button>`

    - **CFG** settings (not functional in Demo)
    - **DEL**ete `fieldset.form-group`
  - Each element with an `#id` and `[name]` has a unique suffix (based on `Date.now()` and `Math.random()`).
  - Upon **SUB**mitting `form#frm0` a Link is revealed.

    - Clicking the link scrolls the user to `iframe#response`
    - `iframe#response receives and displays the response from the test server.

#### References

**[Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)**

#### Demo

```js
// When button#ADD is clicked...  
$('#ADD').on('click', function(e) {

  /* Random number to be interpolated in 
  || Template Literal
  */
  var ts = Math.round(Date.now() / Math.random() * 11);

  /* Template Literal is a string with new 
  || syntax and advanced methods and properties
  */
  var str = `<fieldset id='setX${ts}' class='SET form-group'><div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> </span> <input id="name-${ts}" type="text" class="form-control" name="name-${ts}" placeholder="Name"></div><div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> </span><input id="mail-${ts}" type="email" class="form-control" name="mail-${ts}" placeholder="Email"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></i></span><input id="cell-${ts}" type="phone" class="form-control" name="cell-${ts}" placeholder="Phone"></div><div class="input-group pull-right"><div id='setC${ts}' class="btn-group"><button id='CFG${ts}' type="button" class="CFG btn btn-success"> <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></i> </button> <button id="DEL${ts} "type="button" class="DEL btn btn-danger"> <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></i> </button></div></div> <span class="input-group-addon" style="height:35px">${ts}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></span><textarea id="info-${ts}" type="text" class="form-control" name="info-${ts}" placeholder="Info" cols='120' rows='4'></textarea></fieldset>`;

  // Append TL to DOM (string gets parsed as HTML)
  $('#setD').append(str);

  // Register the new button.DEL to click event
  $('.DEL').on('click', DEL);
});

/* This the callback function for button.DEL
|| click event
*/
function DEL(e) {
  // Get the closest fieldset.SET and remove it
  var parent = $(this).closest('.SET').remove();
}

// When form#frm0 is submitted show a#RSP 
$('#frm0').on('submit', function() {
  $('#RSP').show();
});

/* When a#RSP is clicked, scroll to 
|| iframe#response.
|| iframe#response receives the server response
|| and displays it.
*/
$("#RSP").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#response").offset().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#RSP {
  display: none
}
```

```html
-
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>BS Form</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <main class="container">

    <form id="frm0" action="https://httpbin.org/post" method='post' target='response'>
      <div class="input-group pull-right">

        <div id='setA' class="btn-group"> <button id='ADD' type="button" class="ADD btn btn-primary"> <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i> </button> <button id='CFG' type="button" class="CFG btn btn-success"> <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></i> </button>
          <button id='SUB' type="submit" class="SUB btn btn-warning"> <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-send'></i> </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <fieldset id='setB' class='form-group'>
        <legend>Contact Form</legend>
        <a href='#/' id='RSP' class='btn btn-link'>View Response</a>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset id='setD' class="form-group"></fieldset>

    </form>

    <iframe srcdoc='<h1 style="text-align:center;font-family:Consolas">Server Response</h1>' src='about:blank' id='response' name='response' frameborder='1' width='99%' height='300'></iframe>

  </main>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```