# Converty jQuery closest to ES6 to add CSS for bg

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

### Objective

Get the url of each image and add that as a background to it's parent article, in a vuejs project

### Question

How should I refactor the code originally written in jQuery?

---

### JS - original from other author

```
$(".polaroid").wrap("<div class='polaroid-frame'><div class='polaroid-image'>");
$(".polaroid").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var imgLink = $this.attr("src");
  var bg = "url("+imgLink+")";

  $this.closest(".polaroid-image").css({
    "background-image": bg
  });
});
```

### JS - refactored for my project

```
$(".polaroid article img").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var imgLink = $this.attr("src");
  var bg = "url("+imgLink+")";

  $this.closest("article").css({
    "background-image": bg
  });
});
```

[My demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/PBQyev)

---

### Background

I am taking code from another project but it was written in jQuery. I don't want to use jQuery, instead i just need to write this in ES6, or just plain javascript.

I so far found one related question, [Finding closest element without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663941/finding-closest-element-without-jquery) , but it was too different to be able to make much use of it.

I looked at the mozilla documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest , which leads me to think my code should translate to

```
el.closest("article");
```

but then how would I wrap that in a way that would pass the CSS values. I looked up documentation from w3 https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp and found this example

```
document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "blue";
```

So I think I should do

```
document.[unclear what to do here].style.background-image = /* what goes here for the variable? */;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your refactored JS, to translate it into plain JS, you need to

(1) Iterate over the selected elements (can be done easily with `querySelectorAll`)

(2) Get the element's `src` attribute

(3) Set the closest `article`'s `background-image` to that `src`

So, it should be pretty simple:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.polaroid article img').forEach((img) => {
  const { src } = img;
  img.closest('article').style.backgroundImage = `url(${src})`;
});
```

Note that when setting `style` properties directly, sometimes the CSS string you'd want to use (eg. `background-image`) wouldn't be valid syntax in Javascript. In these cases, generally turn the words-separated-by-dashes into camelCase. (`backgroundImage`)