# Simplest way to get parent div for actionEvent handling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im making a button 2d matrix in the format:

```
<table id="board">
        <tr class="row 0">
            <td class="col 0"><button></button><td>
            <td class="col 1"><button></button><td>
            <td class="col 2"><button></button><td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row 1">
            <td class="col 0"><button></button><td>
            <td class="col 1"><button></button><td>
            <td class="col 2"><button></button><td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row 2">
            <td class="col 0"><button></button><td>
            <td class="col 1"><button></button><td>
            <td class="col 2"><button></button><td>
</table>
```

I wanted to make one function when a user clicks on the buttons. My idea was to get the row and the column from the button that is pressed but Im not sure how to do that. In my js script I wanted to do something like:

```
document.querySelector('button').onclick = move("insert button row", "insert button column");
```

I would like any ideas on how to find the parent div or something capable of accomplishing this task.

Comment: Are you using jquery at all?

Comment: No, never used that before.

Comment: @Matthew sir may i send him syntax..May this will help him a lot as he is learning himself

Comment: I suggest learning about it. I'll provide a jQuery way of doing it as well as using non-jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate — [Finding closest element without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663941/finding-closest-element-without-jquery#35294561)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over all the buttons. And you have to assign a function to `onclick`, not call the function. Inside that function, you can use `this` to refer to the button that was clicked, `parentElement` to get the containing element, and `rowIndex` and `cellIndex` to get their positions in the table.

```
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(b) {
    b.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var col = this.parentElement.cellIndex;
        var row = this.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex;
        move(row, col);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) to get the parent element of a particular element.

See example below.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function (e) {
  e.onclick = function () {
    console.log(`This is ${e.nodeName}`);
    console.log(`My dad is ${e.parentNode.nodeName}`);
    console.log(`My grandpa is ${e.parentNode.parentNode.nodeName}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="board">
        <tr class="row 0">
            <td class="col 0"><button></button><td>
            <td class="col 1"><button></button><td>
            <td class="col 2"><button></button><td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row 1">
            <td class="col 0"><button></button><td>
            <td class="col 1"><button></button><td>
            <td class="col 2"><button></button><td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row 2">
            <td class="col 0"><button></button><td>
            <td class="col 1"><button></button><td>
            <td class="col 2"><button></button><td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery way (Needs JS lib inserted on page):

```
$('button').on('click', () => {
    this.parentNode.parentNode; //Retrieves TR tag of the individual button
    move("insert button row", "insert button column");
});
```

Non-jQuery Way:

```
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((e) => {
    console.dir(e); //Reads out of all properties and methods of element in console
  //Inserts click event listener logic if you please
  e.parentNode.parentNode; //Retrieves the TR tag of the button
    move("insert button row", "insert button column");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the event listener to the tr element and then access the target and currentTarget's parent

```
for (var trEL of document.querySelectorAll('tr')) {
  trEl.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'button') {
    move(event.target.parentNode, event.currentTarget)
  }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is one approach you could take.

The benefit of using `closest()` is you don’t have to worry about changing the markup in the future. I would also recommend using `addEventListener()` instead of `onclick` since you may inadvertently override another click event with `onclick` since it is in the global scope (see [Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)).

NOTE: `closest()` requires a polyfill in IE 11- (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Polyfill)

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

buttons.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", evt => {
    let button = evt.target;
    console.log({
      row: button.closest("tr").classList[1],
      columns: button.closest("td").classList[1]
    });
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

button:hover,
button:focus,
button:active {
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table id="board">
  <tr class="row 0">
    <td class="col 0"><button></button><td>
    <td class="col 1"><button></button><td>
    <td class="col 2"><button></button><td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row 1">
    <td class="col 0"><button></button><td>
    <td class="col 1"><button></button><td>
    <td class="col 2"><button></button><td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row 2">
    <td class="col 0"><button></button><td>
    <td class="col 1"><button></button><td>
    <td class="col 2"><button></button><td>
  </tr>
</table>
```